# WSO2 data services server distributed transactions can not roll back for different types of database

Tags: transactions, wso2, distributed, rollback, wso2-data-services-server

I am following [this guide](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS310/Distributed+Transactions+Sample) to test distributed transactions of DSS.

It is OK. The addAccountToBank1 service call rolled back because of the error in addAccountToBank2 operation. In this test, the two operations are both involve H2 DB.

Then I do another test:

In this test, I replace one of the H2 DB to MySQL DB. 
Here are my steps:

1. Run the begin_boxcar  operation.
2. Insert some data to MySQL DB.
3. Run the addToAccountBalanceInBank2  operation and give the values "1" for "accountId" field and "h200" for the "value" field.
4. Run the end_boxcar  operation.
5. Run the getAccountBalanceFromBank2  operation.(The Balance does not change)
6. query the data in MySQL DB.(It has been changed by insert operation)

I do not know why roll back do not happen for MySQL DB?
And what conditions are needed for the roll back of distributed transactions of DSS?

The content of the .dbs file:

```
    <data enableBoxcarring="true" enableDTP="true" name="DTPSampleService" serviceNamespace="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/dtp_sample">
<config id="H2DataSource1">
    <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.xa_datasource_class">org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</property>
    <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.xa_datasource_properties">
        <property name="URL">jdbc:h2:file:./samples/database/DATA_SERV_SAMP</property>
        <property name="User">wso2ds</property>
        <property name="Password">wso2ds</property>
    </property>
</config>
<config id="H2DataSource2">
    <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.xa_datasource_class">org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</property>
    <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.xa_datasource_properties">
        <property name="URL">jdbc:h2:file:./samples/database/DATA_SERV_SAMP2</property>
        <property name="User">wso2ds</property>
        <property name="Password">wso2ds</property>
    </property>
</config>
<config id="MySQL">
    <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.driver">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>                              
    <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.protocol">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customersdatabase</property>                              
    <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.user">root</property>                              
    <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.password">root123</property>  
    </config>
<config id="MySQL1">
  <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.driver">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>                              
  <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.protocol">jdbc:mysql://192.168.31.44:3306/guohtdb</property>                              
  <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.user">root</property>                              
  <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.password">root123</property>  
</config>
<query id="addAccountToBank1Query" returnGeneratedKeys="true" useConfig="H2DataSource1">
    <sql>insert into Accounts (balance) values (:balance)</sql>
    <param defaultValue="0" name="balance" sqlType="DOUBLE"/>
    <result element="GeneratedKeys" rowName="Entry" useColumnNumbers="true">
        <element column="1" name="ID" xsdType="integer"/>
    </result>
</query>
<operation name="addAccountToBank1">
    <call-query href="addAccountToBank1Query">
        <with-param name="balance" query-param="balance"/>
    </call-query>
</operation>
<query id="addToAccountBalanceInBank1Query" useConfig="H2DataSource1">
    <sql>update Accounts set balance = balance + :value where accountId= :accountId</sql>
    <param name="accountId" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
    <param name="value" sqlType="DOUBLE">
        <validateDoubleRange maximum="2000" minimum="-2000"/>
    </param>
</query>
<operation name="addToAccountBalanceInBank1">
    <call-query href="addToAccountBalanceInBank1Query">
        <with-param name="accountId" query-param="accountId"/>
        <with-param name="value" query-param="value"/>
    </call-query>
</operation>
<query id="getAccountBalanceFromBank1Query" useConfig="H2DataSource1">
    <sql>select balance from Accounts where accountId=:accountId</sql>
    <param name="accountId" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
    <result element="Balance">
        <element column="balance" name="Value" xsdType="double"/>
    </result>
</query>
<operation name="getAccountBalanceFromBank1">
    <call-query href="getAccountBalanceFromBank1Query">
        <with-param name="accountId" query-param="accountId"/>
    </call-query>
</operation>
<query id="addAccountToBank2Query" returnGeneratedKeys="true" useConfig="H2DataSource2">
    <sql>insert into Accounts (balance) values (:balance)</sql>
    <param defaultValue="0" name="balance" sqlType="DOUBLE"/>
    <result element="GeneratedKeys" rowName="Entry" useColumnNumbers="true">
        <element column="1" name="ID" xsdType="integer"/>
    </result>
</query>
<operation disableStreaming="true" name="addAccountToBank2">
    <call-query href="addAccountToBank2Query">
        <with-param name="balance" query-param="balance"/>
    </call-query>
</operation>
<query id="addToAccountBalanceInBank2Query" useConfig="H2DataSource2">
    <sql>update Accounts set balance = balance + :value where accountId= :accountId</sql>
    <param name="accountId" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
    <param name="value" sqlType="DOUBLE">
        <validateDoubleRange maximum="2000" minimum="-2000"/>
    </param>
</query>
<operation name="addToAccountBalanceInBank2">
    <call-query href="addToAccountBalanceInBank2Query">
        <with-param name="accountId" query-param="accountId"/>
        <with-param name="value" query-param="value"/>
    </call-query>
</operation>
<query id="getAccountBalanceFromBank2Query" useConfig="H2DataSource2">
    <sql>select balance from Accounts where accountId=:accountId</sql>
    <param name="accountId" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
    <result element="Balance">
        <element column="balance" name="Value" xsdType="double"/>
    </result>
</query>
<operation name="getAccountBalanceFromBank2">
    <call-query href="getAccountBalanceFromBank2Query">
        <with-param name="accountId" query-param="accountId"/>
    </call-query>
</operation>
<query id="insert_customer_query" useConfig="MySQL">
    <sql>INSERT INTO customer(NID,Name,customerID) VALUES(?,?,?)</sql>
    <param name="NID" ordinal="1" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" type="IN"/>
    <param name="Name" ordinal="2" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" type="IN"/>
    <param name="customerID" ordinal="3" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" type="IN"/>
</query>
<operation name="insert_customer_operation">
    <call-query href="insert_customer_query">
        <with-param name="Name" query-param="Name"/>
        <with-param name="customerID" query-param="customerID"/>
        <with-param name="NID" query-param="NID"/>
    </call-query>
</operation>
<query id="select_with_key_customer_query" useConfig="MySQL">
    <sql>SELECT NID, Name, customerID FROM customer WHERE customerID=?</sql>
    <param name="customerID" ordinal="1" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" type="IN"/>
    <result element="customerCollection" rowName="customer">
        <element column="NID" name="NID" xsdType="xs:string"/>
        <element column="Name" name="Name" xsdType="xs:string"/>
        <element column="customerID" name="customerID" xsdType="xs:string"/>
    </result>
</query>
<operation name="select_with_key_customer_operation">
    <call-query href="select_with_key_customer_query">
        <with-param name="customerID" query-param="customerID"/>
    </call-query>
</operation>
<query id="select_all_customer_query" useConfig="MySQL">
    <sql>SELECT NID, Name, customerID FROM customer</sql>
    <result element="customerCollection" rowName="customer">
        <element column="NID" name="NID" xsdType="xs:string"/>
        <element column="Name" name="Name" xsdType="xs:string"/>
        <element column="customerID" name="customerID" xsdType="xs:string"/>
    </result>
</query>
<operation name="select_all_customer_operation">
    <call-query href="select_all_customer_query"/>
</operation>   
<query id="insert_customer_query1" useConfig="MySQL1">
    <sql>INSERT INTO user(NID,Name,customerID) VALUES(?,?,?)</sql>
    <param name="NID" ordinal="1" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" type="IN"/>
    <param name="Name" ordinal="2" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" type="IN"/>
    <param name="customerID" ordinal="3" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" type="IN"/>
</query>
<operation name="insert_customer_operation1">
    <call-query href="insert_customer_query1">
        <with-param name="Name" query-param="Name"/>
        <with-param name="customerID" query-param="customerID"/>
        <with-param name="NID" query-param="NID"/>
    </call-query>
</operation>
<query id="select_with_key_customer_query1" useConfig="MySQL1">
    <sql>SELECT NID, Name, customerID FROM user WHERE customerID=?</sql>
    <param name="customerID" ordinal="1" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" type="IN"/>
    <result element="customerCollection" rowName="user">
        <element column="NID" name="NID" xsdType="xs:string"/>
        <element column="Name" name="Name" xsdType="xs:string"/>
        <element column="customerID" name="customerID" xsdType="xs:string"/>
    </result>
</query>
<operation name="select_with_key_customer_operation1">
    <call-query href="select_with_key_customer_query1">
        <with-param name="customerID" query-param="customerID"/>
    </call-query>
</operation>
<query id="select_all_customer_query1" useConfig="MySQL1">
    <sql>SELECT NID, Name, customerID FROM user</sql>
    <result element="customerCollection" rowName="user">
        <element column="NID" name="NID" xsdType="xs:string"/>
        <element column="Name" name="Name" xsdType="xs:string"/>
        <element column="customerID" name="customerID" xsdType="xs:string"/>
    </result>
</query>
<operation name="select_all_customer_operation1">
    <call-query href="select_all_customer_query1"/>
</operation>
</data>
```

Comment: Can you please post the content of the relevant .dbs file here.

Comment: I have added the content of the relevant .dbs file.Please confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you didn't have propely configured the MySQL datasource as an XA datasource. Please use this sample configuration for the "MySQL" datasource in your case.

```
   <config id="MySQL">
     <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.xa_datasource_class">com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.xa_datasource_properties">
         <property name="URL">dbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customersdatabase</property>
         <property name="User">root</property>
         <property name="Password">root123</property>
      </property>
   </config>
```

Please find more from [here](http://sparkletechthoughts.blogspot.com/2013/10/distributed-transaction-with-wso2-data.html).

Thanks

Chanika

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works!

I still have a problem.

This configure seems can not be finished by the wizard of the console.

But can only through the way of directly editing the dbs file.

If a developer is unfamiliar to dbs file, it will not finish this configuration.

Comment: If you are willing to add the data source as an XA datasource then you have to add it as an external data source from the wizard by giving necessary properties. Please refere the 'Data source provider' section in http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS310/Data+Sources.

Comment: Do you know how to configure the XA datasource of Oracle and MongoDB?

Comment: The oracle xa driver class in oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource